# Understanding the field of fractions of $F[[x]]$ (the ring of formal power series in the indeterminate x with coefficents in F)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F[[x]]$ be the ring of formal power series in the indeterminate x with coefficients in F. Show that the field of fractions of $F[[x]]$ is the ring $F((x))$ of formal Laurent series.

I've been going in circles on this one for what seems like ever now! If anyone could lend me some insight I would be exceedingly grateful! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:

A formal power series in $F[[x]]$ is invertible if and only if its constant term is not $0$ (more generally, a formal power series  in $R[[x]]$, $R$ being a commutative ring, is invertible if and only if its constant term is a unit in $R$).

Let $p$ be the order of  a formal power series. It can be written as
$$\sum_{k\ge p}a_k x^k=a_px^p\Bigl(1+\frac{a_{p+1}}{a_p}x +\frac{a_{p+2}}{a_p}x^2+\dotsm\Bigr),$$
i.e. as the product of $\;a_px^p$ by an invertible power series. So in order to find the reciprocal of  the formal power series, you just have to find the reciprocal of $x^p$.

Answer (score 4):

$\sum_{k=-n}^\infty a_kx^k=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k-n}x^k}{x^n}$, so every Laurent series can be written as a quotient of power series.

Conversely, given a fraction $\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$, write $G(x)=a_nx^n(1+xH(x)),$ where $H(x)$ is a power series. Then
$$
\frac1{G(x)}=\frac1{a_nx^n}\cdot \frac{1}{1+xH(x)}=\frac1{a_nx^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^kH(x)^k
$$
When $H(x)^k$ is expanded into powers of $x$, and like terms are collected, the above writes $\frac1{G(x)}$ as a Laurent series. Since Laurant series are closed under multiplication, $F(x)\cdot \frac1{G(x)}$ is also a Laurent series.

Comment: Could you give a pointer for deriving that $$ \frac{1}{1 + xH(x)} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k H(x)^k$$?

Comment: @Anakhand Geometric series formula.